# Javascript hasOwnProperty always false on Event objects?

Tags: javascript, events, clone, hasownproperty

I was hoping somebody could help clarify the hasOwnProperty() method with relation to Event Objects.

I am trying to clone a mouse event (eventually this object will be passed to an iframe)
I have already built a 'clone' function - but whenever i attempt to clone a window event (ie scroll, click etc) all instances of 'hasOwnProperty()' return false. 
For example, i iterate over the object - using hasOwnProperty() to check - and each property is returning false. 
This works for standard objects - but not event objects.

Is this because all of the properties within the event objects are inherited? 
Or is there an issue with the code?

Any enlightenment would be appreciated :)

Code snippet:

```
function cloneObject (o_node) {
 var newObject = {};

  for (var child_node in o_node) {

    if (o_node.hasOwnProperty(child_node)) {
    //no object properties are returning true at this point. 

    newObject[child_node] = o_node[child_node];

    }else{
    console.log("!hasOwnProperty()");
    }
  }
 return newNode;
}

function onclick(e){

   var cloned_object_e = cloneObject(e); //returns an empty object;

}

window.addEventListener('click', onclick);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your assumption is correct - the `e` argument is a hollow `new MouseEvent` object that has no own properties, only those inherited from the prototype chain `MouseEvent<-UIEvent<-Event`. Here's the inheritance diagram:

[image]

Comment: May I ask where did this diagram come from?

Answer (score 0):

You created an object called `newObject`, but you returned an object called `newNode`, which you never defined or added anything to. Try changing your return statement to this:

```
return newObject;
```

I think this will give you an object with some properties that the event itself has.

Comment: ooops! thanks eddyjs. 
that was a typo when copying it - in the real code it's the same name. 
:)